# Using collections in a click and display scenario in Angular - Angular vs Blazor approaches

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, blazor

to help determine the UI framework direction for a development team, I am currently evaluating both Angular 8 and Blazor. The team currently uses C#, so the inclincation towards Blazor seems natural. But some say that Blazor still qualifies as a "release 1" risk, so to balance things out I'm also exploring Angular as an alternative.

The use case is a very simple one, similar to an e-mail UI. A list appears on the left with message titles and dates and, when one is clicked, the full text of the clicked message appears in a larger space to the right. It's a basic click and display scenario. Click on the left and display on the right.

Knowing C# fairly well, I was able to put this together in Blazor relatively quickly using classes and foreach loops. Using a simple "Message" class with properties, I can loop through the messages and display each inside a List collection. Here are some snippets of that code (this is an early POC, so it still has some rough edges):

```
public class Message
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" 
   data-toggle="list" 
   href="#home"     
   role="tab" 
   @onclick="() => popIt(0)"
>
    <span id="msgSubject1">@Message[0].Subject</span>
    <br />
    <span class="datetimeCls" id="datetime1">@Message[0].DateCreated</span>
</a>

<div id="messageMenuBar">
    <div class="messageTitleSection">
        <span class="theMessage" id="messageTitle">@Subject&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
        <span id="messageDate">@DateCreated&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="textDiv" id="home">
    <p class="textDisplay">@MessageText</p>
</div>
```

"popIt()" on the @onClick() calls a function that returns the message number from the List colection and then displays the message properties based on the passed number in the second code block. This appears to work, though it needs some polishing.

Not knowing Angular as well as C#, though I have some high-level basics down, I'm going through a small struggle to replicate parts of this scenario in that framework. I seem to have the basic click display set up in a component using interpolation and inline click events and an onClick() method, also called "popIt()" in the component.ts file:

```html
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" 
   data-toggle="list" 
   href="#home" 
   role="tab" 
   (click)="popIt(1)"
>
    <span id="msgSubject1">{{MessageSubject1}}</span>
    <br />
    <span class="datetimeCls" id="datetime1">{{MessageDateCreated1}}</span>
</a>
```

The roadblock has come with iterating through the equivalent of the Message object and its properties in TypeScript. I know that TypeScript doesn't have the equivalent of "List<>" out of the box, so is it recommended to create one's own List functionality? Or could "Map" fulfill this instead? Or some combination of that with an ngFor? Right now I have hard-coded messages ("Message1," "Message2," "Message3," etc.) in the component.ts file, so they display correctly and some of the clicking works. But it would be great to have the equivalent functionality of iterating through a series of object structures with properties, which would presumably work similarly to the Blazor code. I've been researching some approaches with Angular and I'm still looking.

Other information: both of these POCs use Visual Studio 2019 (the team has used Visual Studio for years). The Angular version uses the Angular Visual Studio template (specifically v8.2.12).

Any suggestions, thoughts, opinions or directions would be appreciated! I can also post more code if  needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am currently evaluating both Angular 8 and Blazor. But some say that Blazor still qualifies as a "release 1" risk, so to balance things out I'm also exploring Angular as an alternative.

One more consideration: Blazor is server-side rendering while Angular is client side. Server side can mean more load on your servers.

There is also [Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.1), but that's still in preview so you might want to avoid that.

> The team currently uses C#, so the inclincation towards Blazor seems natural.

Typescript was created by the same person who created C# and uses a lot of the same conventions. You'd be surprised how easy it would be for a C# developer to pick up. Devs might have an issue with some of JavaScript's irregularities, which you would avoid by picking Blazor.

> The roadblock has come with iterating through the equivalent of the Message object and its properties in TypeScript.

Use `Array<T>` in Typescript if you want the functionality of `List<T>` in C#. The JavaScript [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) should have all the features you need for your use case. On the angular side, use `ngFor` for iteration. Example:

**example.component.ts**

```js
interface Message {
    Subject: string;
    Body: string;
    DateCreated: Date;
}

...

public messages: Array<Message>;
```

**example.component.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let msg of messages; let i = index">
 <!-- Think of this as foreach(var msg in messages) equivalent in C# -->
 <span>{{ msg.Subject }}</span>
 <span>{{ msg.Body }}</span>
 <span>{{ msg.DateCreated }}</span>
</div>
```

I can prepare a better demo if you're interested.

You can use Visual Studio for developing Angular apps, but VSCode would work better. It has more features and is faster. For Blazor, you need Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: thank you for your response, that definitely points me in a possible direction. Unfortunately, the question was closed (my first one ever on this site), so I don't know if you'll even see this comment. If you have something more developed, it would be great to see, but I really appreciate your help on this!